# Flag for migration and vote to close, or only one of those?

Tags: discussion

If a question is off-topic here and seemingly on-topic for another SE site, should it be flagged for moderator attention to have it migrated, or should it be voted for closure, or both? I just did both to a question, but it occurred to me that maybe it's better to only do one or the other.

Comment: Both is best IMO, but I don't know if there is any guidance from SE on this.

Comment: Ok, good to know. As long as both isn't bad in any way. I just wanted to make sure I wasn't making things harder for mods - like maybe you couldn't migrate it if it's closed or something.

Comment: I think we have to re-open it and then close it via migration, but it's not a big deal :)

Comment: My last flag for migration was declined with the message that the question was not high enough quality for migrations, along with the pithy quote, "don't migrate crap". So... I guess only **good** questions that are off-topic here should be flagged for migration.

Comment: That was me. The "pithy quote" is used all over SE,  sorry if it came across as harsh -- I ran out of space in the decline message for more info.  But yes,  we want to make sure that the receiving site will want the question and that it won't just be immediately closed (which is also an awful experience for the asker,  being pingponged around).

Comment: It wasn't **too** harsh. No hard feelings.